# Formatting lost down the pipes

Tags: node.js, unix, pipe, chalk

You can give it a ride yourself, below is the code in copy-able format.

Here's `chalked.js`

```
var chalk = require('chalk');

console.log('Immediately!');

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(chalk.red('Right after!'));
}, 400);

setTimeout(function () {
    process.stdout.write('And ' + chalk.magenta('...'));

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(chalk.underline('it\'s gone!'));
    }, 2000);
}, 5000);
```

Then there's `piper.js`

```
process.stdin.pipe(process.stdout);
```

[image]

How can I preserve color formatting through these pipes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I can tell, Chalk [disables colour support when not writing to a TTY](https://github.com/sindresorhus/has-color/blob/master/has-color.js).  It looks like you need to supply the [`--color` arg](https://github.com/sindresorhus/chalk#chalksupportscolor).

You can also set the environment variable `FORCE_COLOR=1` to force colors for anything that uses Chalk.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, chalk is not writing to anything it is building a string.  Maybe FORCE_COLOR=1 allows process.stdout.write to accept color.